# Teradata / Report Buildeer 3.0 cast date between 2 different data types

Tags: sql, teradata, reportbuilder3.0

I want to add a selection criteria to my SQL for a Report Builder report.  The user will select a 'from' and 'to' date, e.g., `11/1/2015` and `12/31/2015` with prompts.  The sql runs good and brings back everything.  I'm trying to narrow the selection to a specific date range.

The date column `jsdate` in the table is `Decimal (8,0)`.  When I look at the dates in this column it looks like `20,150,612`, `20,150,609`, `20,150,611`, etc.

I'm trying to add a selection critieria like

"`and cast(jsdate as date format 'mm/dd/yyyy' between 11/1/2015 and 12/31/2015`".

I'm sure I have the syntax wrong but I don't know how to correct it.  Thanks for your help......

```
select jsdate, jsn, junit, jmyear, jmake, jmodel, jseries, jbuyid
from vehicle_mgmt.AA0888
where jfinowngp = 'B1' and jfinownbr = '99'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Teradata stores dates using following formula:(year - 1900) * 10000 + month * 100 + day, so try:

```
  select jsdate, jsn, junit, jmyear, jmake, jmodel, jseries, jbuyid
    from vehicle_mgmt.AA0888
    where jfinowngp = 'B1' and jfinownbr = '99' and 
CAST(jsdate - 19000000 AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') between 
CAST('2015/11/05' AS DATE) 
and CAST('2015/12/31' AS DATE)
```

Comment: @haytem............that didn't work.  the sql ran but didn't produce any results.  I tried to add a field like this: cast(jsdate as date format 'mm/dd/yy') as New_Date, to the results and 20150612 displayed as 6/12/3915 and 20150609 displayed as 6/9/3915.  I'm guessing that is why no results were returned since 6/9/3915 wasn't between 11/5/15 and 12/31/2015.  Thanks for looking at this....

Comment: @haytem..........Thank you very much.  That worked like a charm.  I really appreciate your help with this.  Thanks again.